# Compare data from table with another table with apache POI in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to compare the data from table 1 with all data from table 2 (Line by line), the problem is, how could i iterate `.getRow(1)` to compare row by row of table 1?
I mean; we are comparing data from table 1 and row 1 with all lines of table 2. When the process ends I would like to continue with `.getRow(2)` thanks (Code updated)

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        int numRows2 = workbook2.getSheetAt(0).getPhysicalNumberOfRows();   
        int numRows = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        int num = 0;
        int num2 = 1;
        while(numRows!=0) {
        numRows--;  
        String dato = formatter.formatCellValue(workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(num2++).getCell(1));
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows2; i++) {
            
            String val = formatter.formatCellValue(workbook2.getSheetAt(0).getRow(num++).getCell(1));
            
            if (dato.contains(val)) {
                System.out.println("Works " + val);
            }else {
                System.out.println("No match");
            }
                        
        
        }
        }
```

Comment: there's also an example class, for a bit more compares: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/ss/ExcelComparator.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, this code works in case someone needs it.

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        int numRows2 = workbook2.getSheetAt(0).getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        int numRows = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        // int num = 0;
        int num2 = 1;
        while (numRows > 0) {
            numRows--;
            int num = 0;
            String dato = formatter.formatCellValue(workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(num2++).getCell(1));
            for (int i = 0; i < numRows2; i++) {

                String val = formatter.formatCellValue(workbook2.getSheetAt(0).getRow(num++).getCell(1));

                if (dato.contains(val)) {
                    System.out.println("Works " + val);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No match");
                }

            }
        }
```